# How to disable individual button in a list?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i have a list of items (dynamically created) and each item has respective button to delete. I am trying to disable individual button upon onclick. I am able to disable single button using disabled prop and setState. However, this may not suit my current use case which the list items are dynamically created. If using the setState method, i might need to create additional state for each item created.

Thanks for your advice.

Edit :
I would like to generate a list of N items, each item with a delete action button. And, each delete button should be disabled after first click for processing (to prevent double click).

As mentioned, it might not be a good idea use 'disabled={condition}' on button. It is because the list is dynamically created which has N number of items. If using the method ('disabled={condition}'), i will need to have N number of state variable to keep track each and everyone delete button.

```
<List>
{ items.map( item => 
   <ListItem>
      <ListItemText
          primary="Single-line item"
          secondary={secondary ? 'Secondary text' : null}
       />
   <ListItemSecondaryAction>
       <IconButton aria-label="Delete">
           <DeleteIcon />
       </IconButton>
   </ListItemSecondaryAction>
  </ListItem>
  )
}
</List>
```

Comment: Hi can you show some code otherwise it'll be difficult to help...

Comment: That's very vague but you could try something like disabled={condition ? true : false}

Comment: @RicardoCosta, or even `disabled={condition}`

Comment: @t3__rry, thanks for the reply. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this ,
Ex :

```js
let button_variables = [
{
    label:"save_btn",
    isDisabled : false
},
{
   label:"cancel_btn",
   isDisabled : true
}
]

and then u can map those to the buttons something like below ,

button_variables.map(function (data, index) {
  <button disabled={data.isDisabled}> {data.label} </button>
});

Note :  If disabled didnt worked means, u can change className dynamically instead of that .
Ex : 
className = {data.isDisabled ? activeClass : disabledClass}
```

Comment: this method will work for fixed number of buttons. However, if i have a list of dynamically created buttons, I will need to have many state variable to keep track every single one of them. thanks anyways.